# Communicate Zync Module with Android tablet

Tags: android, linux-kernel, vhdl, fpga, zynq

I got a Trenz Electronic TE0720 Zync Module from school that I want to do something with. I want to make a project that sends and receives data between the Zync Module and an Android tablet. The communication will happen through Ethernet communication.

After some research I learned this:

- Need to build Linux kernel inside the processing system in Zync Module
- I probably need to go through the internet to be able to communicate with the tablet. (I want to     communicate through a local network).

I'm not sure where I should start. I have some experience with Android development, VHDL and Linux (OS level, not kernel level). Where should I start and what should I do to be able to make such a project?

Thank you :D

Comment: Building the Linux kernel for the Zynq is fairly easy with the Petalinux tools of Xilinx (>= 2014.4)

Comment: @vermaete Thanks, I'll check that out :) But what about the communication between the Zynq Module and the Android tablet? Any suggestions?

Comment: Nop, just use the eth0 of the Zynq and use ethernet.  Put that eternet at a wireless router and done.  In fact, almost or none VHDL/FPGA is involved.

Comment: Another solution could be using the USB port and put a small Wifi dongle in it (http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).

Comment: @vermaete sorry for late response. I really appreciate your answers. Just a quick question; if I would want to save some parameters from sensors connected to the Zynq, how should I make a database to view those parameters later on the tablet? :)